# How to get multiple collections of rows grouped by some column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know there is `GROUP BY` clause but it doesn't seem to fulfil my needs.

I have a table with rows having `year` column each, with values, say, from 2000 to 2018. There are also some other columns in this table, say, `value`, `user`.

Is it possible with a SQL query to receive all the rows but as different sets, like this:

```
year | value | user
-------------------
2017 | 150   | john
2018 | 163   | jack
2003 | 125   | john
2018 | 175   | jack
```

I want to have sets like this:

```
2003: 
     125 | john
2017: 
     150 | john
2018: 
     175 | jack
     163 | jack
```

My current solution is just to receive all rows then group them using the logic of the language of the app. Is there a way to move this on to the shoulders of SQL?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with [tag:javascript]?

Comment: use ORDER BY for year instead

Comment: This kind of formatting should be done  in the front-end. SQL is not a language to do report formatting.

Comment: please "draw" a resulting table?..

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8ba1e3bb9727de3fb5080eecdf9611d4

Answer (score 0):

`group by` works with aggregat functions, like count, min, max, together.

You could use `order by year`, as needed and group where the output takes place.